# Need to know Autowirecapablebeanfactory autowireBean lifecycle

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I was using Autowirecapablebeanfactory autowireBean which i came to know that not to use it.

But then also I need to know when we autowire the bean then that object get created with all the dependency but how this object get distroyed when i am not distroying that object explicitly.

Comment: Official Spring Docs says..Integration code for other frameworks can leverage this interface (Autowirecapablebeanfactory) to wire and populate existing bean instances that Spring does not control the lifecycle of.... so bean in application context without scope i guess.

Comment: Default scope is prototype...but as spring docs says.....?!@#$#